I don't understand what distribution means
From the Rudin book:

We can therefore assign a " kth derivative " to every f that is
locally integrable: $f^{(k)}$ is the linear functional on $D$ that
sends $\phi$ to $(-1)^k \int f\phi^{(k)}$. Note that $f$ itself
corresponds to the functional $\phi \rightarrow \int f\phi$.

Does it mean $f(x) = \int f(x)x$ and it's an example of a distribution?

The map $\phi \mapsto \int f \phi$ is the example of a distribution.  It is a linear functoinal on $\mathcal D$.

I think the idea is that $f$ gets identified with the functional $\phi\mapsto \int f\phi$. That identification is an injective (essentially, modulo a.e. vanishing functions) linear transformation. The situation is not unlike what happens when number system is extended from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Q}$. An integer $n$ is identified with the equivalence class of $\dfrac n1$.

Short exposition about distributions
Notation

$L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R)$ denotes the space of locally integrable functions on $\mathbb R$.
$C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ denotes the space of $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that the support of $f$ is compact.

Linear functional induced by function
Let $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R)$. Then $f$ induces a linear functional $T_f$ on $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ by, for $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$, setting
$$T_f(\phi) := \int f(x)\,\phi(x)\,dx.$$
Derivatives
If $f$ is differentiable and also $f'\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R)$ then, by integration by parts,
$$T_{f'}(\phi) = -T_f(\phi').$$
Note that the right hand side is defined even if $f'\not\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R)$. We can therefore define the distributional derivative of $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R),$ denoted $T_f',$ by
$$T_f'(\phi) = -T_f(\phi').$$
This definition extends to arbitrary order:
$$T_f^{(k)}(\phi) = (-1)^k T_f(\phi^{(k)}).$$
Identifying function with induced functional
Note that the mapping $f\mapsto T_f$ is even an injection; if $T_f=T_g$ then $f=g$ (in the sense of $L^1$). It is therefore common to identify $T_f$ and $f$ and just write $f$ when one actually means $T_f.$ Therefore it is also common to write $f^{(k)}$ when one really means $T_f^{(k)}.$
Distributions
By a distribution we mean almost any linear functional on $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$. I write "almost" since there is a continuity condition, but we can leave that for now.
The most well-known example of a distribution is Dirac's delta, defined by
$$\delta(\phi) = \phi(0),$$
where $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R).$
It's a fact that $\delta$ is not induced by any $h\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R).$
Derivatives of distributions
Based on the identity $T_{f'}(\phi) = -T_f(\phi')$ we define the derivative of a distribution $U$ by
$$U'(\phi) = -U(\phi').$$
For example, the derivative of Dirac's delta is given by
$$
\delta'(\phi) = -\delta(\phi') = -\phi'(0).
$$
Also, the derivative is the Heaviside function $H,$ defined by
$H(x) = 1$ if $x>0$ and $H(x)=0$ if $x<0$ (the value at $x=0$ doesn't matter), is $\delta$:
$$
H'(\phi) 
= -H(\phi')
= -\int H(x) \, \phi'(x) \, dx
= -\int_0^\infty \phi'(x) \, dx
\\
= -(\phi(\infty) - \phi(0))
= \phi(0)
= \delta(\phi)
$$
for all $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R)$ since $\phi(\infty)=0.$
